# Alexa, taking notes and send them via mail

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I'd like to learn to write Alexa Skills, so I thought a Skill, that records the users speech and writes it down, to send it to him via mail later, would be pretty cool.

I managed to let the user Start the Skill but I have no idea how to save the "notes" of the user. I havent found anything on google, so I tried to ask here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to realize my problem. 
Here is my solution:
Intent (Utterances are in German, but the Slot {NoteInput} is important)

```
{
"interactionModel": {
    "languageModel": {
        "invocationName": "mail notes",
        "intents": [
            {
                "name": "AMAZON.CancelIntent",
                "samples": []
            },
            {
                "name": "AMAZON.HelpIntent",
                "samples": []
            },
            {
                "name": "AMAZON.StopIntent",
                "samples": []
            },
            {
                "name": "noteIntent",
                "slots": [
                    {
                        "name": "NoteInput",
                        "type": "AMAZON.SearchQuery",
                        "samples": [
                            "notiere {NoteInput}",
                            "{NoteInput}"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "samples": [
                    "und schreibe auf {NoteInput}",
                    "und notiere {NoteInput}",
                    "notiere {NoteInput}",
                    "sende mir folgendes",
                    "und schreib auf",
                    "und notiere",
                    "notiere",
                    "und schreib mit",
                    "schreib mit",
                    "schreib auf"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "dialog": {
        "intents": [
            {
                "name": "noteIntent",
                "confirmationRequired": false,
                "prompts": {},
                "slots": [
                    {
                        "name": "NoteInput",
                        "type": "AMAZON.SearchQuery",
                        "confirmationRequired": false,
                        "elicitationRequired": true,
                        "prompts": {
                            "elicitation": "Elicit.Slot.61384016725.485372519591"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "prompts": [
        {
            "id": "Elicit.Slot.61384016725.485372519591",
            "variations": [
                {
                    "type": "PlainText",
                    "value": "Sehr wohl, ich trage zu protokoll"
                },
                {
                    "type": "PlainText",
                    "value": "Gerne, ich notiere"
                },
                {
                    "type": "PlainText",
                    "value": "Sehr wohl, ich notiere"
                },
                {
                    "type": "PlainText",
                    "value": "Gerne, ich schreibe mit"
                }
            ]
        }
}
```

}

As you can see the Slot {NoteInput} got AMAZON.SearchQuery as Slottype. This will cause Alexa to simply transfer Speech-to-Text.

The Handler in the Lambda-Function looks like this:

```
 const inProgressNoteIntentHandler = {
   canHandle(handlerInput) {
     const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
    return request.type === 'IntentRequest'
      && request.intent.name === 'noteIntent'
      && request.dialogState !== 'COMPLETED' ;
  },handle(handlerInput) {
     const currentIntent = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent;
     return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .addDelegateDirective(currentIntent)
      .getResponse();

  }
};

const completeNoteIntentHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
      && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'noteIntent';
  },handle(handlerInput) {
    const filledSlots = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots;
    const slotValues = getSlotValues(filledSlots);
    console.log("Folgende Slots im noteIntent " + slotValues.NoteInput.synonym);


      noteArr.push(slotValues.NoteInput.synonym);
      console.log(noteArr.toString());



      return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak("Ok, ich habe " +slotValues.NoteInput.synonym+ " notiert.")
      .getResponse();

  },


};
```

You'll need this function to get the Value of the Slot:

```
function getSlotValue(slot){
    let value = slot.value;
    let resolution = (slot.resolutions && slot.resolutions.resolutionsPerAuthority && slot.resolutions.resolutionsPerAuthority.length > 0) ? slot.resolutions.resolutionsPerAuthority[0] : null;
    if(resolution && resolution.status.code == 'ER_SUCCESS_MATCH'){
        let resolutionValue = resolution.values[0].value;
        value = resolutionValue.name;
    }
    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As of today, this use case can not developed with a Skill. There is no API to allow to capture raw user or speech recognition input only.  A skill receives the result of speech recognition *and* natural language understanding, expressed as an Intent and a set of entities.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your Answer. Could you check the solution i provided in my answer? I works fine for me, but your answer sounds like the AMAZON.SearchQuery SlotType is not meant to be used in this way.

Comment: Indeed. The SearchQuery slot is trained on generic searches data and might not be accurate to recognize general data from many different domains, such as meeting notes. I would suggest to try and to experiment, and measure the accuracy for your use case before taking the decision to continue using it in this context.